# Install mate-dock-applet for MATE panel on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: 18.04, panel, mate, dock

I would like to have icons in the MATE desktop environment panel for all open applications. Found a solution located in the PPA `webupd8team/mate` called `mate-dock-applet`. I use 18.04. When trying to add the repo I get an error though:

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Cannot add PPA: ''This PPA does not support bionic''.
```

Is there any other way to install mate-dock-applet in 18.04 or is there anything similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS. It has this package in the *universe* repository.

> [image: MATE Dock Applet]

It is also available in all other Ubuntu versions:

```
$ rmadison mate-dock-applet
 mate-dock-applet | 0.70-1build1 | xenial/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 mate-dock-applet | 0.85-1       | bionic/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 mate-dock-applet | 0.87-1       | cosmic/universe | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 mate-dock-applet | 0.87-1       | disco/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
```

So you do need any PPA to get it working.

Moreover [the `ppa:webupd8team/mate` PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/mate) does not support 18.04 LTS (bionic). Consider to remove it from your `sources.list`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:webupd8team/mate
sudo apt-get update
```

and then simply install the package with

```
sudo apt-get install mate-dock-applet
```